# Can I manually switch off booster fans that are coupled with HVAC blower?

Tags: hvac, fans

Could not get upstairs in 1900 craftsman bungalow cooled with HVAC system until the contractor inserted a booster fan in each of the two ducts. Fans are coupled to the blower of the HVAC. Now in fall and probably throughout winter it gets way too hot upstairs. Is there a safe (and easy) DIY way to disconnect the fans from the blower to just have normal air flow going upstairs or would the fans block the airflow if not powered?

Thanks in advance!

Pictures show how the fans were hooked up to the blower control board.

Tom[image][image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How are the fans coupled to the HVAC blower?

Comment: can you reach the fan?

Comment: It depends on your HVAC unit but my booster fans for upstairs bedrooms are wired such that they kick on when the unit is calling for cooling, but not when calling for heat. They don't significantly affect the already poor flow (hence the need for a booster) through those ducts when they are not operating during the winter.

Comment: Both fans are wired to the hvac blower by a single cable. Unfortunately, they did not wire it to only switch on with cooling which would have been nice. It is a brand new American Standard Silver unit. Can I just put a wireless switch on the line going out to the fans? I found one but it is restricted to 10 A - I guess the two fans should not drag more than that?

Comment: Assuming the heat isn't already on the high speed terminal, which is where the AC should be, if you wired it there it'd only come on when it calls for AC. How is *the blower* wired? (can't really tell from the picture). *'Both fans are wired to the hvac blower'* - what color wire or terminal? And what's the model number to find the manual so we know what should be wired where. They either arbitrarily did it wrong, or did it wrong for a reason (e.g., they put the heat on the high speed terminal).

Comment: Can you post the wiring diagram for the air handler?

Comment: I added pictures of the wiring diagram.

Comment: They might have put the blowers on the high speed because that was the only way to get AC really work upstairs but I really do not want the fans in winter as it is 90 degrees upstairs and 63 downstairs...

Comment: Can you post the exact model number of the furnace please? It looks like they're using the control board's EAC function for the auxiliary blower, which seems sensible enough, but we'll need to make certain of the behavior of that function before we start bolting stuff onto this.

Comment: AUH2B060A9V3VBA

Comment: Do you want the boosters to run when the system has its fan forced ON manually at the thermostat, or do you want them to *only* run when air conditioning is being called for?

Comment: Heat was sufficient upstairs before putting booster fans into the two ducts. I hope the air flow with turned off booster fans will still be enough. Is it easy to try how it works to just have them come on with AC - and if that does not work out - then put them on forced fans? Alternatively, can I just add a WiFi switch on the line connecting the fans to the furnace?

Comment: @Tom -- yeah, we can try it with AC only first, and then switch it to run them on a call for fan later (the switcheroo will just be a matter of moving a wire)

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - how do I do it? Do I move both contacts and how are they fixed to the board. I have never done this before...

Comment: Is the heat currently on high blower settings? Can this be returned to variable and then only when the air is needed fix it to high blower speed?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel please help me with my last question.

Comment: @Mazura please help me with my last question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's been abandoned.

Answer (score 0):

### You'll need to add an extra *fan relay* to your system to accomplish this

Your existing setup controls the booster fans via the EAC terminals on the furnace control board, which appear to be energized whenever the furnace blower is running.  In order to change this, you'll need to stick a *fan relay* in line with the control wiring to the fans, so that the fan only comes on during the correct conditions (cooling, in your case).  For this, you'll need:

- A SPST-NO HVAC relay (these have 24VAC coils, quick-connect terminals, and flange mounting means)
- Two short lengths of 18/2 thermostat cable (enough to get from the control board to the relay, and another shorter length to serve as a pigtail)
- A length of 14AWG stranded THHN wire (about the same length as the thermostat wire, can be any color save for white, grey, or green)
- Four female quick-connect terminals (two red ones for 18AWG wire, two blue ones for the 14AWG wire), as well as two wirenuts suitable for 4x18AWG wires
- A couple of self-drilling sheet metal screws, suitable for attaching the flanges on the relay to the inside of the furnace wiring compartment
- And a screwdriver + wire-cutter/stripper (of course) and a ratchet-type crimper with an insulated terminal die (these are *the* way to go for crimping things, the cheap crimp pliers are not a good way to get uniformly reliable crimps)

The installation goes as follows (if you aren't comfortable with this, any HVAC tech or electrician should be able to do this on your behalf):

1. Turn power to the furnace off (the service switch will suffice), and open up the wiring compartment of the furnace
2. Find an empty spot near the control board to mount the control relay at, and use the mounting screws to attach it to the inside of the wiring compartment there
3. Crimp the red quick-connects onto the wires on one end after stripping the wires on both ends of the longer length of thermostat cable
4. Strip both ends of both wires on the shorter length of thermostat cable
5. Crimp the blue quick-connects onto the ends of the 14AWG wire after stripping them as well
6. Remove the black wire with the quick-connect terminal on it from the EAC-H terminal on the control board, and move it to one of the *contact* terminals on the new relay
7. Use the 14AWG jumper you made in step 5 to connect the other *contact* terminal on the relay to the EAC-H terminal on the control board
8. Remove both wires from the Y terminal on the control board, and connect one wire in the short length of thermostat cable to the Y terminal.  Take the matching wire in other end of the short length of thermostat cable, and nut it to the existing Y wires as well as to one wire in the long length of thermostat cable
9. Repeat the process of step 8 with the wires connected to the C terminal on the control board and the free wires in the two lengths of thermostat cable you added. If there's only one wire connected to C, that's no big deal -- this will set you up properly later if you need to run a C wire to a thermostat down the road.
10. Connect the quick-connects on the other end of the thermostat cable to the *coil* terminals on the new relay
11. Button the wiring compartment back up and turn the service-switch back on

Now, the booster fans should only work if the thermostat is calling for air conditioning.  If you want them to run during a call for fan, you'll need to rewire things so that the fan relay's coil is wired between G and C on the control board, instead of between Y and C as it is at the moment.

Comment: Is the heat currently on high blower settings? Can this be returned to variable and then only when the air is needed fix it to high blower speed?

Comment: @Tom -- the blower setting the heat is using doesn't matter, since we're using the EAC terminals on the furnace board instead of tapping the fan motor leads directly

Comment: Thanks. Just to make sure - I think the HVAC guy who did this job set the blower to always high because the AC did not cool enough upstairs. When following your solution will this be reversed but when AC is triggered go back to high settings?

Comment: @Tom -- this will not impact the setting of the main blower

Comment: Is this an appropriate relay?
https://www.amazon.com/Emerson-380-Relay-Volt-Coil/dp/B000LDCPQS

Comment: @Tom -- there's no sense in  trying to order this stuff from Amazon.  You should be able to find a suitable one at the big-box stores, or through a local HVAC or electrical supply house for that matter

Comment: after talking to a local HVAC supply store owner, I decided to go for an inline switch cutting the control cable to the booster fans. Seems to work and I was told it will not harm the HVAC system. Is this correct?

Comment: @Tom -- it's basically the manual version of what the relay I propose does, so yeah, it'll be fine if you want to go the manual route